# How to make a counter in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

So I want to count not how many letters/numbers are entered into a text field
But how many times something has been entered into the field itself, I was thinking of just making my "Calculate" button a click count but that would still allow some one to just click the button and it would +1 to the counter with nothing in the field. So I was wondering if there was a way to do it that you would have to input text into the field to add to the counter.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub CalculateButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CalculateButton.Click
    Answer = Minutes * TIME_RATE
    TotalChargeBox.Text = Answer.ToString("N")
    NumGroupsBox.Text= Counter.ToString("N")
    AvgAns = Answer / Counter
    AvggroupBox.Text = AvgAns.ToSting("N")
```

Everything works but when I click calculate the NumGroupsBox will only display 0
at the moment til I learn how to get the counter function to work.

Can some one please help advise me on how I can go about doing this?

Comment: Although you tried your best to explain the problem, you are still not providing enough information for us to help you. Please rephrase the question. As of now: we don't know what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Guessing from your source sample, this is not `VB6` code, but `VB.Net` code. Please tag accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

WebForms applications can use the `TextChanged` event handler for `TextBox` controls to detect when the value has been modified. Each time the field is changed, the web browser does a `PostBack` to the web server and the "changed count" can be calculated. Here is an ultra basic example:

ASPX page:

```
Enter value:
<asp:TextBox ID="TrackedField" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
<hr />
This field has been changed
<asp:Label ID="TimesChanged" runat="server" Text="Enter value" />
times.
```

ASPX.VB page:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If ViewState("TimesChanged") Is Nothing Then ViewState("TimesChanged") = 0
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
    TimesChanged.Text = DirectCast(ViewState("TimesChanged"), Integer).ToString()
End Sub

Protected Sub TrackedField_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TrackedField.TextChanged
    ViewState("TimesChanged") = DirectCast(ViewState("TimesChanged"), Integer) + 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

If I am not mistaken, you want to keep the counter running as long as the application is running, right?
One of the simplest way to do it, is to create a textbox on your form (which you can Hide if needed by setting the `Visible` property to 'False'), let's call it `txtCounter`.

On initialisation of your form (FormShown event), you will initialise the counter (to zero most probably) as `txtcounter.Text = 0. Then comes your Click event, which you can maintain as you are already doing;

```
Private Sub CalculateButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CalculateButton.Click

    ' Increment counter
    Counter = CInt(Counter.text) + 1

    Answer = Minutes * TIME_RATE
    TotalChargeBox.Text = Answer.ToString("N")
    NumGroupsBox.Text= Counter
    AvgAns = Answer / Counter
    AvggroupBox.Text = AvgAns.ToSting("N")

    ' Re-assign to textbox
    Counter.text = Counter.ToString
```

This should do for you.